# Files containing only exports decreases the test coverage Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I'm using create-react-app which uses Jest for testing.
I have `index.js` files containing exports lines like

```
export { default } from './App.component';
```

which decreases the test coverage of my application.

**Q:**
How to test such files or at least ignore them?

Answer (score 4):

You can ignore these files using a `collectCoverageFrom` config in your jest configuration.

```
    {
       "jest": {
           collectCoverageFrom: [ 
              '<yourDirectoryStructure>/**/*.{js,jsx}', 
              '!<yourDirectoryStructure>/**/index.{js,jsx}',
           ]
       }
    }
```